# Как сделать вывод информации из JSON не строкой, а списком?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Всем привет, такой вопрос, как наладить вывод из JSON информации не строкой, а списком.
И если такое вообще возможно, чтобы он выводил значения уже в формате кнопки, на которую просто можно нажать

```js
function select_company()
{
  var chbx_list = collect_checkboxes();
  var amount = chbx_list.length;
  console.log(chbx_list);
  csrf_token = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
  $.ajax({
      url : "/blockchain/", // the endpoint убрать первыйс слуеш в случае неудачи
      type : "POST", // http method
      data : {chbx_amount : amount,
              checks_list : chbx_list,
              csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token }, // data sent with the post request

              success : function(json) {
                    // console.log(json);
                document.getElementById('companies').innerHTML = json.companies.join(', ');            

                  },

                  // handle a non-successful response
                  error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                    console.log("error");
                  }
      });
      return false;
}
```

Comment: Строка чудесным образом не может превратиться в `<li>`, решение напрямую зависит от структуры JSON. (используя JSON.parse перебрать объекты, завернуть необходимые строки в li).

Comment: Возможно ли тогда то что он выводит строкой, выводить в формате ссылки и друг под другом?

Comment: А попробуйте заменить `json.companies.join(', ');` [ на угад ] → `'<ul><li>' + json.companies.join('</li><li>') + '</li></ul>';` ?)

Comment: Всё равно выводит строкой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился.

```js
function select_company()
{
  var chbx_list = collect_checkboxes();
  var amount = chbx_list.length;
  console.log(chbx_list);
  csrf_token = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
  $.ajax({
      url : "/blockchain/", // the endpoint убрать первыйс слуеш в случае неудачи
      type : "POST", // http method
      data : {chbx_amount : amount,
              checks_list : chbx_list,
              csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token }, // data sent with the post request

              success : function(json) {
               let lisString = "";
for (const company of json.companies) {
    const li = `<li>${company}</li>`;
    lisString+=li;
}
document.getElementById("companies").innerHTML = lisString;          

                  },

                  // handle a non-successful response
                  error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                    console.log("error");
                  }
      });
      return false;
}
```

```html
<div class="leadOut">
  <p>Подходящие компании</p>
   <ul id="companies"> </ul>
</div>
```